# List with exclusive options

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list of options that are being fed to a rest call like so:

```
[ 'allX', 'noX', 'noY', 'allY', 'var1', 'var2' ]
```

(The actual list is quite long)

Only one of '*X' can be included.
Only one of '*Y' can be included.
Any of the single item variables like var1 and var2 can be used with any combination of options.

Basically I wanna avoid a long kludge of if-then statements checking if allX and noX were provided together, ditto for the next pair, and so on.

Is there a handy python module for doing this or what is the most pythonic way of asserting this requirement? I have no control over the list itself, so tackling this from that end is not an option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried smth like len(filter(lambda x: x.endswith("X"), your_list)) == 1 ?

Comment: Do things literally end with `X` and `Y`, or can those things be arbitrary values?

Comment: Sorry the list is very diverse and complex. After looking at this again I don't think there is a slick way of doing this. =(

Comment: If there is any rhyme or reason to the structure of the those special values, there may be ways to do it. But if it's just a bunch of arbitrary values where some things have special meanings and others don't, then that's tough to work with.

Answer (score 3):

To cut down on control statements, you can try this:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

new_data = list(chain.from_iterable([[list(b)[0]] if a.isupper() else list(b) for a, b in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x[-1])]))
```

Output:

```
['allX', 'noY', 'var1', 'var2']
```

To make your algorithm as generic as possible, you can try this:

```
s = [ 'allX', 'noX', 'noY', 'allY', 'var1', 'var2' ]
import re
last = []
second_last = []
for i in s:
    if re.findall("[A-Z]$", i):
         if i[-1] not in second_last:
              last.append(i)
              second_last.append(i[-1])
    else:
       last.append(i)
print(last)
```

Output:

```
['allX', 'noY', 'var1', 'var2']
```